# What's 24 in "192.168.15.0/24"?

Tags: networking, routing

What's the meaning of `/24` in the following command?

```
    route add -net 192.168.15.0/24 192.168.8.10
```

Comment: I may be wrong (I haven't used Windows `route` for a while), but that gateway is from a different subnet.

Or is this just a made up example?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It is the short way of representing a subnet mask.

As Steffen Opel points out in his [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/196444/whats-24-in-192-168-15-0-24/196553#196553), this is called [CIDR notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR_notation) and the number simply indicates the prefix size used to construct the subnet mask.

So `/n` means that the first `n` bits (out of 32 for IPv4) are set to `1`, the rest are set to `0`. To convert this to a decimal subnet mask you write it in to four octet's and convert to decimal.

So `/24` produces `255.255.255.0` because you have twenty four `1` bits and then eigth `0` bits:

```
Binary:   11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000
Decimal:    255      255      255       0
```

The short value doesn't have to be a multiple of 8 (ie, it doesn't have to end of the octet boundaries), for example you can take `/20` to get `255.255.240.0` as so:

```
Binary:   11111111 11111111 11110000 00000000
Decimal:    255      255      240       0
```

### Usage with IPv6

The same notation can be appiled to IPv6 as well. Since IPv6 uses 128 bits, instead of 32, the addresses are *much* larger. I won't go in to the full semantics here, because it's not relevant to the question, but will provide a quick example:

The subnet given in the question is represented by `192.168.15.0/24` and includes all the IPv4 addresses from `192.168.15.0` to `192.168.15.255`

An IPv6 subnet can be represented in the same way, for example `2001:DB8::/48` contains all IPv6 addresses in the range `2001:DB8:0:0:0:0:0:0` to `2001:DB8:0:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF`.

<sup>Note: IPv6 example shamelessly ripped from the [Wikipedia CIDR article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR_notation).</sup>

---

For more info on Subnet masks themselves, what they mean and how the are used, I would recommend you see the question [What are the essentials of a Subnet mask?](https://superuser.com/questions/186850/what-are-the-essentials-of-a-subnet-mask/186949)
Or look at the *extensive* answer to [How does Subnetting Work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work/49836#49836) over at Server Fault.

Comment: Each octet is 8bits: 11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000

Comment: So does that mean /16 is 255.255.0.0 and /8 is 255.0.0.0?

Comment: @Corey yes. And - as per Joe's binary there - just stick in the right number of one's, add enough 0's to reach 32, split in to four bytes and convert to decimal. It doesn't have to be a multiple of 8 either - `/20` is `255.255.240.0` for example.

Comment: very good, professor DMA57361

Answer (score 16):

DMA57361s answer of this representing a [subnet mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) is correct and sufficient already (+1) - I'd still like to offer a different approach in explaining this to provide some background regarding the history/motivation for this notation:

"192.168.15.0/24" is the compact specification of an IP address and its associated routing prefix, expressed in [CIDR notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR_notation):

> CIDR notation is constructed from the IP address and the **prefix size**, the latter being the number of leading 1 bits of the routing prefix.  [emphasis mine]

The referenced short Wikipedia article already explains the topic at hand nicely; for a more thorough explanation of many related aspects you might consult the respective parent topic [Classless Inter-Domain Routing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) - in particular you'll find there information about the historical [Background](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#Background) for the [change](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#Subnet_masks) from *subnet masks* to *prefix length/size*.

Finally, for a good and intuitive representation on how to interpret these notations when you encounter them in practice you might look at the tables within [IPv4 subnetting reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_subnetting_reference) as well.

Comment: Adds some good depth to the topic. +1

Answer (score 0):

The /24 is the subnet 255.255.255.0. The /{number} at the end of an IP address is known as [CIDR Notation](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/workingwithipaddresses/a/cidr_notation.htm).