# How to interpret IP signs?

Tags: ip

This is what my provider gave me:

76.73.118.160/29

So how many IPs do I have and what are the IPs?

That does 29 means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is [CIDR notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing). The /29 means that 29 bits out of the 32 are the network part, and the last 3 bits are for addresses. In this case, you will have 8-2 (6) IP addresses available.

The reason? With three bits available, the range of address are (binary) 000-111 (0-7). Two are reserved: All 1's for the Netmask, and one more for the network address (0). The common ranges of addresses for private subnets are usually 192.168.x.y/24, meaning the first 3 decimal numbers (first three bytes) are for the network