# What does /16,/24 mean with regards to ip addresses?

Tags: networking, ip

I am trying to understand how network topologies work in large scale networks such as college campuses.

I often see the phrases /16,/24 with regards to ip addresses.

I would like to know what /16 and /24 etc. mean. I understand it has something to do with subnet masks, but my question is different.

Let's say one of /24 ip address is 124.125.126.* with subnet mask 255.255.255.0, and it can have 256-2 hosts.

I am assuming we are talking about **public ips** here.

What does hosts mean here? Is it 254 router can be assigned public ips here? We don't assign public ips to end user devices, they only get private ips. so I am confused what does hosts refer to here?

Answer (score 39):

/16, /24 is called *CIDR notation*, it's a different way to express the subnet mask.

A subnet mask can be used for any IP, public, private, etc.; the /X has nothing do really whether the IP is public or private.

Electronic equipment processes IP addresses as a string of 32 bits that can either be 1 or 0.  It only cares about the 1's and 0's; writing it as decimal numbers is for our benefit, not any router, computer, phone, etc.

The 4 decimal numbers in an IPv4 is just a shorter way to write them so we don't have to write all the 0's and 1's.

The way the 4 decimal numbers relate to those 0's or 1's is like the below. Wherever there is a 1, add that number to that set of 8 bits to get the decimal number for that "octet".

```
1                 1                 1                 1               
2 6 3 1           2 6 3 1           2 6 3 1           2 6 3 1         
8 4 2 6 8 4 2 1 . 8 4 2 6 8 4 2 1 . 8 4 2 6 8 4 2 1 . 8 4 2 6 8 4 2 1    

--------------- . --------------- . --------------- . ---------------

1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0   1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1

--------------- . --------------- . --------------- . ---------------

192             . 168             . 0               . 5
```

Net masks are always a long string of 1's followed by a long string of 0's.  It determines what part of the IP identifies the network (the 1's) and what part identifies the computer/phone/host/etc.

That works like this:

```
1                 1                 1                 1               
2 6 3 1           2 6 3 1           2 6 3 1           2 6 3 1         
8 4 2 6 8 4 2 1 . 8 4 2 6 8 4 2 1 . 8 4 2 6 8 4 2 1 . 8 4 2 6 8 4 2 1 

--------------- . --------------- . --------------- . ---------------

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 . 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 . 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

--------------- . --------------- . --------------- . ---------------

255             . 255             . 255             . 0

                      1 1 1 1 1 1   1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2   2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7   8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5   6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3   4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1

--------------- . --------------- . --------------- . ---------------

_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _   *

or /24
```

CIDR just says we can simply say the number of 1 bits without writing out the four decimal numbers of the subnet mask.  So you can write 192.168.0.5/24 instead of 192.168.0.5/255.255.255.0.

Comment: Since OP question is looking at topology, I would add that this changes behavior when mapping - /24 will preserve the first 24 bits (eg: 255.255.255, or 192.168.0) as "fixed network" and iterate the remining 24 bits. This is why you see /8 /16 /24. Technically you could scan the lower half of block with /25...etc down to /32 (which is 1 address). This also comes in very useful if you want to just look at local Interfaces since most OS will reserve a single block per Interface by default (/23).

Comment: @Elysiumplain you write "/24 will preserve the first 24 bits...and iterate the remaining 24 bits." => the second should be "8" I guess

Comment: Thanks @andymel, your edit is correct. I would delete and re-comment, but that's something for meta Exchange I suppose (or why else would they timeout edits).

Comment: Cool! Now I understand where the sub-net mask comes from.

Answer (score 8):

> I would like to know what /16 and /24 etc. mean. I understand it has something to do with subnet masks, but my question is different.

You could even say that it *literally is* a different way of writing the same subnet mask.

All valid subnet masks consist of a series of 1-bits followed by 0-bits (no mixing), so 255.255.255.0 is commonly written as /24 because it has twenty-four 1-bits. (Similarly /16 equals 255.255.0.0.)

(This number also directly corresponds to the length of the "network part" of the address, so it is often called the 'prefix length'.)

> I am assuming we are talking about public ips here.

Actually that's irrelevant. Routing and subnetting work identically with private and public addresses.

(The only thing that even makes 10.x or 192.168.x "private" is policy – all ISPs and operators have agreed to never route it between each other, in accordance to RFC1918. Other than that, they're normal addresses.)

> What does hosts mean here? Is it 254 router can be assigned public ips here? We don't assign public ips to end user devices, they only get private ips.

No. Any device can be assigned any kind of IP address; it does not have to be a router. The **only** technical reason end user devices usually get private IPs is because the network simply doesn't have enough public ones.

However, if the network *does* have enough public IP addresses for its needs, it can perfectly well assign them directly to hosts. (That's usually done with servers in particular, but there's nothing that would technically prevent any random PC or even a phone from being directly assigned a public IP address.)

So when the text says "hosts", it means "any kind of IPv4-speaking devices".

Comment: RE Any device can be assigned any kind of IP address: I am sure router only get public ip address not private.

Comment: No. Only the "border" routers – those connecting your network to your ISP – need public IP addresses. In a large campus network, there will be multiple levels of routing, and the "internal" routers can perfectly well have any kind of address.

Comment: @Dude that depends as well. Your router might as well be behind an ISP's router, in which case, your router does not have a public address. The ISP's router has and it routes traffic to your router.

Answer (score 1):

Hosts here refer to assignable public IPs. If you're given the entire /24 block, you can have 254 routers (x.x.x.1 to x.x.x.254) each with private networks behind them when using [PAT/NAT Overload](https://www.freeccnastudyguide.com/study-guides/ccna/ch10/10-4-nat-overloading-aka-port-address-translation-pat/). One or more addresses in the block would probably be reserved for an outbound ISP's router for Internet connectivity.

If you don't want the routers all on the same LAN you would need to [subnet](https://www.9tut.com/subnetting-tutorial) the address space into smaller networks, in which your /24 address space could be used to make two /25 networks, or four /26 networks, and so on.

Comment: You can connect any networking device to the network.  This means you can connect multiple routers which each of their own intranet, which can all access a larger network, it is not clear why you are confused by that concept.  It does appear your confusion goes beyond the ability to address your confusion in a comment though.

Comment: The use of subnet masks are to identify the address space of the _local network,_ or _subnet._ If you did not break down the /24 into smaller subnets, all your routers would have to be interconncted using a switch so that they are all communicating in the same LAN/subnet. A single subnet's address space cannot be assigned to multiple interfaces on routers; each must have a unique subnet (otherwise the router would not know how to make routing decisions), which is why you would need to do subnetting.

Answer (score 1):

> Let's say one of /24 ip address is 124.125.126.*, and it can have 256-2 hosts.

124.125.126.1/24 would result in a router being able to assigned a device an IP address between 124.125.126.1 and 124.125.126.254.  You could assigned the same device 62 different IP Addresses if you really wanted to, it would have to have 62 networking ports to acomplisht that realistically, or have every ip address in the subnet redirected to the same device.

> I am assuming we are talking about public ips here.

124.125.126.* would indeed be a valid public ip address.

> What does hosts mean here?

It simply means a device that is connected to the intranet network itself.

> We don't assign public ips to end user devices, they only get private ips. so I am confused what does hosts refer to here?

A private IP Address is simply an IP Address that can only be access another device on the same intranet network. A public IP Address can be access by another device on the internet.  *The meaning of Internet and Intranet due to their prefixes is better left to a lesson in the English language though.*

It does not actually make a difference between a private and public IP Address a /24 subnet would both result in the ability to assigned 62 hosts an IP Address.  /16 would result in 65,534 hosts (i.e. 124.125.0.1 - 124.125.255.254).